# How do I make an endless road in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity

Basically I created 2 quads side by side and I added a road texture. I used transform.translate so that the road moves, but I am trying to make the road endless by making the 2 quads reposition themselves in front of the current quads repeatedly so that when I add a player the road is endless. Any way I could do this? [image]

Comment: Have you heard about the Möbius strip already?

Comment: If the road is straight you could scroll the texture on the road instead of moving the car along the road.

Comment: I tried that but it looked really weird. I'm not sure if you know about queues but that's honestly what it seems I need to use. I just don't know how to write a queue in Unity.

Comment: For a straight road, scrolling the texture  is visually equivalent to moving along an infinite road FYI!  You should probably ask a new question about how to implement a queue in c# (probably on stack overflow)

Comment: If you want to have a car on the endless road then scrolling the texture wont work. The physics engine just wont interact with it, plus other object o the road wouldn't move..

Comment: @ott-- I'm curious...how would you make that (in pseudo code)?

Comment: @Evorlor A bit of math is needed: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_strip#Geometry_and_topology

Answer (score 6):

You could have 2 sufficiently long road segments. Place them one after another. When player moves from one road segment to another, remove the segment which is (now) behind the player, to the front of the current segment.

Comment: Yup I think you mean a queue? I did try to make one but I have no idea how to create one. All I know is that I am supposed to use Dequeue and Enqueue but my problem is I have no idea on how to implement ( code wise)

Comment: @TomOliver Just check when a road segment is not visible, and then place it in front of the other

Answer (score 3):

Many infinite runners scroll the road rather than move the player forwards on the road to make the road truly infinite. You can do this with 2 alternating game objects.

```
public GameObject[] RoadPieces = new GameObject[2];
const float RoadLength = 100f; //length of roads

const float RoadSpeed = 5f; //speed to scroll roads at
void Update ()
{
    foreach (GameObject road in RoadPieces)
    {
        Vector3 newRoadPos = road.transform.position;
        newRoadPos.z -= RoadSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
        if (newRoadPos.z < -RoadLength / 2)
        {
            newRoadPos.z += RoadLength;
        }
        road.transform.position = newRoadPos;
    }
}
```

Just space the roads out correctly in the beginning, and this'll scroll them forever.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the answer of Vinayak Garg is good but since you work with perspective this won't be perfect. This is basically paralax mapping and works great for 2D games. But here you want to have the road dissapear in the horizon probably. If your road is straight then just extent on this technique and add many pieces until it is looking good. Whenever you leave a piece behind move it to the front.

If you want a curvy rode you have to look in procedural algorithms to generate a path for you can use pieces to correct this path. Perlin noise for example can be used for "infinite" randomization. They use it for minecraft in 3D, you just probably just need a 1D variant that just controls the the curve of the road. ANyway, this is a lot harder to implement.